# South letting syncdb do all the job

Tags: django, django-south

When I try to run syncdb so django can create its tables and south's tables, it creates its tables south's and other app that it should not create, south should.
Look:

```
Patricks-Mac-mini:tsm_telecom patrickbassut$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table south_migrationhistory

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): no
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - 
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

**Here, I added the app to INSTALLED_APPS just to try to trick django, or whatever that is.**

```
Patricks-Mac-mini:tsm_telecom patrickbassut$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table tb_lines
Creating table tb_location
Creating table tb_company_lines
Creating table tb_company
Creating table tb_client
Creating table tb_bills
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > core
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - 
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
Patricks-Mac-mini:tsm_telecom patrickbassut$ python manage.py schemamigration core --initial
ValueError: Empty module name
```

Sorry forgot my settings.py. Sending it as requested:

```
# Django settings for tsm_telecom project.
import os


DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

WORKDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

ADMINS = (
    ('Patrick Bassut', 'patrickbassut@hotmail.com'),
    # ('Luis Henrique', 'hacker_wap@yahoo.com.br'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'tsm_telecom',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    WORKDIR + '/static',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'w*+f*_!)%2kzsbqwszj0amt5_rt-q*njruutvy97n88mr08ci!'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_related.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_related.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    WORKDIR + '/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'core',
    'south',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}


if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        # Debug Toolbar https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar
        'debug_toolbar',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
        'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )
```

Comment: show us your settigs.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must generate migrations first `python manage.py schemamigration core --initial`. South doesn't block `syncdb` for apps that don't have `migrations` directory with `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: You're right, that works! Therefore, I thought that south overwrote syncdb command, isn't that right?

Comment: Only for apps that have migrations. If it would override for other apps you would not be able to sync apps build-in django without modyfying Django (adding migrations).